# How can I power my MacBook Pro during trans-Atlantic flights?

Tags: macbook-pro, charging

What is Apple's solution for powering MacBooks on intercontinental flights?  My 85 watt power supply trips most airline seat power supplies, which are rated at only 75 watts.  What's a poor trans-Atlantic worker to do to keep his MacBook Pro charged in-flight?

Answer (score 1):

You could get one of those external battery packs. Hyper makes them specifically for MBPs. This is the link for rMBP: http://www.hypershop.com/HyperJuice/2-External-Battery-for-MacBook-iPad-iPhone-USB-100Wh/